# Jest-Puppeteer testing on GitLab CI with : TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jestjs, puppeteer, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running an e2e test for testing a Google Chrome extension on GitLab CI, using Jest and Puppeteer. The tests pass during development on my local machine, but when I implement it using GitLab CI, it gives the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined.

Complete test logs can be found here: https://gitlab.com/adityabisoi/aossie-scholar/-/jobs/672660422